SMD diode identifying marking AEW
I am trying to identifying the following SMD.  As I can see on the circuit maybe is a transistor or a mosfet.


What are the package dimensions? What kind of device is from? Who is the manufacturer?

Hello. I dont know the manufacturer , its from a electronic gate controller .

The dimensions are 1.5mm * 1.5mm. Maybe is a transistor because it says Q500 on the pcb
